# Improving UITableView scrolling

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview

i stuck with some issue of UITableView scrolling. I know that there are numbers of this question and some solutions. However from technical view like (how exactly to do that) i can't find solutions.

Well in my case scrolling is not so smooth because of images in it. It takes lots of time to load it from file. Also i create custom UITableViewCell and using XiB.

These images is using not 1 time but several, the good idea would be to keep them in memory and to load them just once from file. However in my case there could lots of images and app don't have so many memory to keep them. Maybe there are other way to load these images ?

Also images is PNG, maybe i should change type to JPG ?

I would appreciate if someone would give other solutions to improve this scrolling.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method in tableview delegate to reuse table cells ?

Comment: Use SDWebImage, one line of code if you have the URL to the image. https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Yes i am reusing cells and i don't have a link and doing some operation before adding to UIimageView so i can't use 3-third part code